Finding position of element on array with Java
How can I find the position of an element within an array in Java?
I do not need to print the element; I need to print the middle of the array element position.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    //I need to find the middle array and in this example of the code middle array is 3 and it is in index 2.
        }
    }

In this code how can I print a middle index number?
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int aSize = 0;
    if(scan.hasNext()){
        aSize = scan.nextInt();
    }

    int[] a = new int[aSize];
    for(int i = 0; i < aSize; i++ ){
        if(scan.hasNext()){
            a[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }


Why not a[aSize / 2]?

If the array has an even number of elements, for example {1, 2, 3, 4}, then what is the index of the middle element? Is it 1 (one) or is it 2 (two)?

so basically int mid = a.length/ 2; System.out.printf("middle is at index %d and has value %d%n", mid, a[mid]); (missing checks for empty array, for missing values, and for an even number of elements [no middle element])

Address has a specific meaning in programming. I changed that term to “position” in your Question.

Please use precise and correct language; it will help readers understand better. When you say in the comment //I need to find the middle array it implies there are multiple arrays. You mean "the middle element of the array."

... assuming this question is not asking for the median or even the mean value

I also thought this looks quite 'median-ish'. Of course if it is about medians, it would be better not to assume pre-sorting

To get the middle of an array you could just try accessing array[size/2]. If size is not even and you want to be sure to get the 'lowest' half or the 'highest' half. You could use the function ceil (The ceil() method rounds a number UP to the nearest integer) and floor (The floor() method rounds a number DOWN to the nearest integer) to access array[Math.floor(size/2)] or array[Math.ceil(size/2)]

The functions Math.floor and Math.ceil return double type, but array indexing requires int. Also, assuming size is an int, you will need to use floating-point division, i.e. either (int) Math.ceil((double) size / 2) or (int) Math.ceil(size / 2.0).
